# Python 3. Gi repository. Vte

Tags: python

Нужна библиотека **Vte** для **python 3**. Как её найти? Находил лишь для **python 2**.

Comment: тоже жду, когда запихнут в pygi-aio

Comment: а может уже включили?

Comment: а, кстати vte3 можно на линуксе прицепить через gi

Answer (score 2):

**VTE3** может быть подключен в **Python 3** через **GI**.

```
from gi.repository import  Vte

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("mainwindow.glade")
builder.connect_signals(self)
scrolledterminal = builder.get_object("scrolledterminal")
terminal = Vte.Terminal()
scrolledterminal.add(terminal)
```

Вот пример плохой замены этого виджета для Windows приложений https://github.com/alex-eri/mssh/blob/master/terminalwidget.py